# Calling a method from other class, inside other method

Tags: java, arrays

I couldn't find a solution anywhere, so here it is:

A school project says that to use `isEqual(Student)` method I must use the `hasSameName(Person)` inside it.
I have created two classes, `Student` and `Person` where `boolean hasSameName(Person persons[])` compare the names inside the array and returns `true` if same name found and `false` if there's no same person.

```
public class Person{
    private String name,surname,address,email,phoneNumber;

    public Person(String name,String surname,String address,String email,String phoneNumber) {

        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    }
...
...
...

public boolean hasSameName(Person persons[]) {

        boolean flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i<persons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j< persons.length; j++) {
                if((persons[i].getName() == persons[j].getName() && (i!=j))){
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(flag == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

The project says that `boolean isEqual(Student name, Student id)` should compare the name and the id values but `hasSameName(Person)` method must be used.

Here is the `Student` class:

```
public class Student extends Person {

    private int studentID,semester;

    public Student(String name,String surname,String address,String email,String phoneNumber,int studentID,int semester) {

        super(name,surname,address,email,phoneNumber);
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.semester = semester;

    }
.
.
.
.

    public boolean isEqual(Student name,Student id) {
         //****************i am stuck here. I don't know how to make it work.*******************
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the meaning of your `hasSameName` method?  Isn't it supposed to compare name of current Person `this.name` to the given Person?  What's the use of checking if _all_ persons have the same name?  Btw, use `equals()` instead of `==` to compare objects

Comment: This homework says that we need to check if there's the same person in the array we made and it can be done by checking the `name` variable. (Teacher says)

Comment: Then where are you supposed to get the array of persons when calling `hasSameName` from inside `isEqual` ??  Why isEqual has two Student arguments - there's one student with a name and another with ID?  You can create an array of these two instances, but what for?  You see, I got stuck at the same place because this task seems to be lacking some logic.  Wish you good luck in mastering Java!

Answer (score 1):

*A school project says that to use isEqual(Student) method I must use the hasSameName(Person) inside it.*

I assume that `hasSameName` method should have been implemented like this:

```
// Person.java

public boolean hasSameName(Person person) {
    if (null == person || null == person.getName())
        return false;
    return person.getName().equals(this.getName());
}
```

Then, as `Student extends Person`, you can simply call parent's methods from the child class.  So, providing that the signatures of `hasSameName` and `isEqual` have been fixed, `isEqual` may be implemented this way:

```
// Student.java

public boolean isEqual(Student student) {
    return this.hasSameName(student) && this.studentID == student.getStudentID();
}
```